Visnetwork not displaying visLegend properly
I am using the package VisNetwork and one of the attributes of the nodes contains 9 different possibilities, as follows. This is just a minimal example. In my real dataset, the column "family" has 9 different options.
id name       family
1  cat        mammal  
2  dog        mammal  
3  mushroom   fungi 
4  coral      cnidarian
5  salmon     fish

With the visLegend argument, I have tried to create  a legend for each one of those groups with their corresponding colors, using the following code:
visLegend(addNodes = list(
    list(list = "group a", color = colors[1]),
    list(list = "group b", color = colors[2]),
    list(list = "group c", color = colors[3]), 
    list(list = "group d", color = colors[4]),
    list(list = "group e", color = colors[5]),
    list(list = "group f", color = colors[6]),
    list(list = "group g", color = colors[7]),
    list(list = "group h", color = colors[8]),
    list(list = "group i", color = colors[9])), useGroups = FALSE, width = 0.09) 

However, when it produces a network, while the colours and shapes are present, there is no legend (no words), like this:

Does anyone know why this happens? I tried the same colour for less groups (3 and 5) and it worked, but for this one it doesn't seem to be working.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
